# TypeError: Cannot read property 'right' of null

Tags: qml

I'm trying to understand M/V architecture within the QML. For that I have created a simple program which uses `ListView` `Delegate` and a `Model`. Everything works fine but when I scroll down the view window it shows the follow error: "*TypeError: Cannot read property 'right' of null*"

The QT-Creator shows the problem in the anchors i used in the `Rectangle` Element.
Here is my working example:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4

Window {
    id: mainwindow
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("App title")

   ListModel {
       id: modelName

       ListElement { name: "alpha" }
       ListElement { name: "beeta" }
       ListElement { name: "gamma" }
       ListElement { name : "theta"}

       ListElement { name: "alpha" }
       ListElement { name: "beeta" }
       ListElement { name: "gamma" }
       ListElement { name : "theta"}

       ListElement { name: "alpha" }
       ListElement { name: "beeta" }
       ListElement { name: "gamma" }
       ListElement { name : "theta"}

       ListElement { name: "alpha" }
       ListElement { name: "beeta" }
       ListElement { name: "gamma" }
       ListElement { name : "theta"}

       ListElement { name: "alpha" }
       ListElement { name: "beeta" }
       ListElement { name: "gamma" }
       ListElement { name : "theta"}

       ListElement { name: "alpha" }
       ListElement { name: "beeta" }
       ListElement { name: "gamma" }
       ListElement { name : "theta"}

   }

   Component {
       id: delegateName
       Rectangle {
           readonly property ListView __lv: ListView.view
           id: selected_item_rect
           height: txt.height
           width: txt.width
           color: __lv.currentIndex === model.index ? "grey" : "transparent"
           anchors {
               left: parent.left             // Error is shown here
               right: parent.right           // Error is shown here
           }

           Text {
               id: txt
               text: model.name;
               font.pixelSize: 25
               //           Component.onCompleted: { console.log("Create : ", model.index, model.name) }
               //           Component.onDestruction: { console.log("Destroyed : ", model.index, model.name) }

           }
           MouseArea {
               anchors.fill: selected_item_rect
               onClicked: __lv.currentIndex = model.index
           }
       }
   }

   ListView{
        id: lv
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: modelName
        delegate: delegateName        
        clip: true

        onCurrentIndexChanged: console.log(currentIndex)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `__lv` instead of `parent`:

```
Rectangle {
   readonly property ListView __lv: ListView.view
   anchors {
       left: __lv.left
       right: __lv.right
   }
}
```

I don't know the exact reason it won't work with `parent`, but I am sure it has to do with the fact that the `Rectangle` does not have a parent within the context where it is declared (`Component` doesn't count in this)